# Whats the difference between this two @wire? why cant I handle the response without break

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

THIS CODE WORKS OK:

```
@wire(getPagedContactList, {
    objectToDisplay: '$objToRender',
    nameSearchKey: '$nameSearchKey',
    maxNrRecords: '$maxf',
    pageSize: '$pageSize',
    pageNumber: '$pageNumber'
})
registro;
```

THIS CODE doesnt WORK, and i need to process the response:

```
 @wire(getPagedContactList, {
    objectToDisplay: '$objToRender',
    nameSearchKey: '$nameSearchKey',
    maxNrRecords: '$maxf',
    pageSize: '$pageSize',
    pageNumber: '$pageNumber'
})
wiredResult({error, data}) {
    this.registro = data;
    console.log('debug ' + this.registro); //here the value its ok, but still get the error..
}
registro;
```

this is the html

```
<template>
<lightning-card title="Datatable Example" icon-name="custom:custom63">
    <div class="slds-m-around_medium" >
        <span>
            <lightning-input
                label="Search Key"
                type="text"
                value={nameSearchKey}
                onchange={handleKeyChange}
            ></lightning-input>
        </span>
        <span>
            <lightning-input
                label="Max records"
                type="number"
                value={maxf}
                onchange={handleMaxRecords}
            ></lightning-input>
        </span>
        <template if:true={registro.data}>                  
            <lightning-datatable
                key-field="Id"
                data={registro.data.records}
                columns={columns}
                show-row-number-column=true
                hide-checkbox-column=true
                draft-values={draftValues}>
            </lightning-datatable>
        </template>
        <template if:true={registro.data}>
            <div class="slds-clearfix">
                <div class="slds-page-header" role="banner">
                    <c-paginator
                        page-number={pageNumber}
                        page-size={pageSize}
                        total-item-count={registro.data.totalItemCount}
                        onprevious={handlePreviousPage}
                        onnext={handleNextPage}
                    ></c-paginator>
                </div>
            </div>
        </template>
        <template if:true={registro.error}>

           <!-- <c-inline-message
            variant="error"
            message="Error retrieving data"
            errors={registro.error}
            ></c-inline-message>-->
        </template>
    </div>
</lightning-card>
```

I get [Cannot read property 'data' of undefined]. Need to do some procesing but get the error first.

Comment: Looks like a syntax error. Remove the trailing reference to registro after the wiredResult function. This should not be there. Also note that the value of registro is different in these two cases. The first is an object with error and/or data while the second is just data.

Comment: @PhilW how should be? I cant remove 'registro' variable declaration.

"The wire service provisions the function an object with error and data properties, just like a wired property."

Comment: Actually you could potentially remove the variable declaration entirely if you wanted to store the result in a "private" variable that isn't reactive. But see my answer which probably covers your specific case.

Answer (score 2):

When you use a function for a wire, but still want reactive behaviour against the result of that wire, you need to introduce a separate variable declaration, like:

```
@track registro;

@wire(getPagedContactList, {
    objectToDisplay: '$objToRender',
    nameSearchKey: '$nameSearchKey',
    maxNrRecords: '$maxf',
    pageSize: '$pageSize',
    pageNumber: '$pageNumber'
})
wiredResult({error, data}) {
    this.registro = data;
    console.log('debug ' + this.registro); //here the value its ok, but still get the error..
};
```

A wire either targets a variable or a function, NOT BOTH. This is covered well in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.apex).

By adding "registro" as tracked you still have your template re-processed to account for changes to this variable (assuming the template references it).

Note that your template will need to be changed to remove ".data" where you reference "registro" unless you change your wire function:

```
@wire(getPagedContactList, {
    objectToDisplay: '$objToRender',
    nameSearchKey: '$nameSearchKey',
    maxNrRecords: '$maxf',
    pageSize: '$pageSize',
    pageNumber: '$pageNumber'
})
wiredResult(result) {
    this.registro = result;
    ...
};
```

If you use the "{error, data}" parameter declaration you are essentially stating that the function receives the two properties in an anonymous object as two separate parameters, whilst using "result" means the function receives the object with error and data properties as a single parameter.

If "registro" is intended to only cover the data received, and the error is to appear in a different tracked variable then use "{error, data}" and assign respectively to the error and registro tracks in the wire's function. This approach strikes me as cleaner.

Final point: the wire function can (and likely will) be called with both error and data as undefined at times and you should allow for this in your usages.